# file_get_contents() Headera already sent

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents, hotlinking

Ok guys I use this code for avoid hotlinking:

```
<?php 
    <img width="150" height="42" src='data:image/png;base64,echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("/USER/images/logo.png"))'>;
?>
```

This code works just fine, and since I include it in all of my page  it cause a problem since the file_get_contents() sent an header, and I can't sent for example another  header in the same page (Where this code is included), for example for do a redirect, how can I fix this problem?
This code come from: [Using PHP function include() to include a png image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463598/using-php-function-include-to-include-a-png-image)

Note that /USER/images/logo.png is a file that isn't in the root!

Comment: You can create a simple function that do the redirect for example and when you need to use it just call the function, in this way the double headers already sent message is gone

Comment: How does a base64 encoded logo prevent hot linking? And why should one want to prevent that?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` does _not_ send a header, by the way.

Comment: @arkascha The logo isn't in the root, the file_Get_Contents() get this file from a non root folder

Comment: And what difference does that make?